# Can I use Fabric.js to overlay a tiled pattern over a transparent image?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to implement a feature in a web app that would allow a user to select a swatch and see what that pattern looks like on a set of curtains. I know I can use HTML5 Canvas / Fabric.js to fill a shape with a tiled pattern, but can I do the same thing on a transparent image? Or maybe a "green screen" type of deal?
To clarify, the image of the curtains would be transparent or a solid color. The user would select from a list of swatches or tiled patterns, and that pattern would repeat on the image of the curtains. Hopefully, that makes sense.
I've never used HTML5 Canvas or the Fabric.js library so sorry if this is a lame question.